# Cursor will not work in package procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to implement this procedure into a package however the package
will not allow me to use the cursor for some reason. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Also when I try to put the procedure into my package a 'enter bind variable' box appears
minus anywhere to input a bind variable and this error

```
Not found
The requested URL /apex/wwv_flow.show was not found on this server
```

My code is

```
  PROCEDURE total_calc(p_order NUMBER)
IS
   c_price product.unit_price%type;
   c_prod_desc product.product_desc%type;
   v_total_cost NUMBER := 0;
   v_c1 REFCURSOR;
   CURSOR c1 IS
      SELECT product_desc, unit_price 
      FROM product 
      WHERE product_id IN (SELECT fk2_product_id 
                           FROM order_line 
                            WHERE fk1_order_id = p_order);
BEGIN
   OPEN c1;
   LOOP
      FETCH c1 into c_prod_desc, c_price;
      dbms_output.put_line(c_prod_desc || ': ' || c_price);
      v_total_cost := v_total_cost + c_price;
      EXIT WHEN c1%notfound;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
   dbms_output.put_line('Total Cost:' || v_total_cost);
END;
```

Here is the code for the rest of the package

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE orders_salary_manage AS
  FUNCTION tax_func (p_sal IN NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER;
  PROCEDURE reduce_price(p_product_id NUMBER, p_sub_price NUMBER);
  PROCEDURE increase_price(p_product_id NUMBER, p_add_price NUMBER);
  PROCEDURE remove_order(p_order_id NUMBER);  
  PROCEDURE add_order(p_order_id NUMBER,
                                      p_order_date VARCHAR2,
                                      p_delivery_date VARCHAR2,
                                      p_customer_id NUMBER,
                                      p_employee_id NUMBER,
                                      p_order_type_id NUMBER);
END orders_salary_manage;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY orders_salary_manage AS
  tot_orders NUMBER;

FUNCTION tax_func (p_sal IN NUMBER)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   tax_rate NUMBER := 0;
   v_netsal   NUMBER := 0;
   v_sal    NUMBER;
BEGIN
   v_sal := p_sal;
IF v_sal > 70000 THEN
   tax_rate := (v_sal * 0.4);
   v_netsal := v_sal - tax_rate;
END IF;
IF v_sal < 70000 THEN
   tax_rate := (v_sal * 0.2);
   v_netsal := v_sal - tax_rate;
END IF;

RETURN v_netsal;
END;


PROCEDURE reduce_price(p_product_id NUMBER, p_sub_price NUMBER)
IS v_price NUMBER;
   e_invalid_price EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  SELECT unit_price
  INTO v_price
  FROM product
  WHERE product_id = p_product_id;

  v_price := v_price - p_sub_price;

  IF v_price < 1 THEN
    RAISE e_invalid_price;
  ELSE
      UPDATE product SET unit_price = v_price WHERE product_id = p_product_id; 
  END IF;

END;

PROCEDURE increase_price(p_product_id NUMBER, p_add_price NUMBER)
IS v_price NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT unit_price
  INTO v_price
  FROM product
  WHERE product_id = p_product_id;

  v_price := v_price + p_add_price;

  UPDATE product SET unit_price = v_price WHERE product_id = p_product_id; 

END;

PROCEDURE remove_order(p_order_id NUMBER)
IS 
BEGIN

  DELETE FROM placed_order WHERE order_id = p_order_id;
  DELETE FROM order_line WHERE fk1_order_id = p_order_id; 

END;

PROCEDURE add_order(p_order_id NUMBER,
                                      p_order_date VARCHAR2,
                                      p_delivery_date VARCHAR2,
                                      p_customer_id NUMBER,
                                      p_employee_id NUMBER,
                                      p_order_type_id NUMBER)
IS new_order NUMBER;
BEGIN


  INSERT INTO placed_order (order_id, order_date, delivery_date, fk1_customer_id, fk2_employee_id, fk3_order_type_id)
  VALUES (p_order_id, p_order_date, p_delivery_date, p_customer_id, p_employee_id, p_order_type_id);

END;
END;
```

Comment: You're working out a cost based on summing the unit prices of the products included in an order?

Comment: Yes There is a table with order lines on and a products table.

I take the product description and price from the products table where it matches the order number the user puts in.

Thanks

Comment: What if the person orders three of a particular product?

Answer (score 0):

This is really confusing.

First off - dbms_output requires special settings for the environment in order to work. And a call to `DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE`, plus packages do have access to a terminal anyway.  Packages do not have your process context, they run in the process context of the db -- which runs without a controlling terminal. If you have to write something use a file -- `UTL_FILE` package is meant for that.

Next
Since you are basically adding up an order, you need a function to return the value.
A procedure is not going to work.  As you coded anyway.

Next 
`v_C1` is not used and makes no sense for your code.  You are not returning a refcursor.

Next
You should consider using a schema for tables with generic table names like that when you decalre a variable.

example:

```
v_foo schema_owner.table_name.column_name%type;
```

Consider this:

```
function total_calc(p_order in NUMBER)
return NUMBER
is
   c_price product.unit_price%type;
   c_prod_desc product.product_desc%type;
   v_total_cost NUMBER := 0;
   --  lose this:  v_c1 REFCURSOR;
   CURSOR c1 IS
      SELECT product_desc, unit_price 
      FROM product 
      WHERE product_id IN (SELECT fk2_product_id 
                           FROM order_line 
                            WHERE fk1_order_id = p_order);
BEGIN
   OPEN c1;
   LOOP
      FETCH c1 into c_prod_desc, c_price;
     -- lose this line: dbms_output.put_line(c_prod_desc || ': ' || c_price);
      v_total_cost := v_total_cost + c_price;
      EXIT WHEN c1%notfound;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
   -- lose this line:  dbms_output.put_line('Total Cost:' || v_total_cost);
   return v_total_cost;
END;
```

In order for this to work it has to inside a
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` a statement. Then - Added to the db schema by a user with correct permissions to create it.

After all that, then you can run it.  Also, there is more to all this package/function creation stuff  like using PRAGMAS if somebody needs to run this from `SQLPLUS`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and advice. I tested this and it seems it still wont work with my package so I have placed it in its own package and now it works fine.